# Access denied http 403 net core 2.2 IIS deployed

Tags: iis, http-status-code-403, asp.net-core-2.2

I developed a REST api web application in net core 2.2

It has been deployed on IIS in HTTPS and works well.

I need to add an authentication by client certificate, so I followed the following steps:

- authentication: disabled
- ssl: certificate required Configuring
- certificate authentication in One to One

Once this is done when I try to access my API I have a 403 error

Using ProcessMonitor I saw that the process was trying to access routes and that it generates "access denied"

[access denied screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ChKS.png)

But it is a REST api, the roads in question do not correspond to a path

I am stuck and need help on this

Comment: Process Monitor is usually useless here. What's the substatus code for that 403 in IIS log files?

Comment: Here a copy a last log file


2019-11-13 14:32:05 XX.XX.X.XX POST /api/Connect/Token - 8080 - XX.XX.XX.XX PostmanRuntime/7.19.0 - 403 7 5 1031


Status code 403.7


Forbidden: Client Certificate Required


OK i see, my client certificate is not provided by postman

Comment: If you find the cause and the solution, post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem

I added the certificate Current user / in intermediate certification authorities

I also have my certicate root and client in Local Computer store (and also intermediate certification authorities)

Finally I added the following key in the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ SecurityProviders \ SCHANNEL]
"SendTrustedIssuerList" = dword: 00000000
"ClientAuthTrustMode" = dword: 00000001
```

And so it works